# What techniques can I use to find position relationship in group of elements?

Tags: neural-network, classification, feature-extraction

I have 14,000 tagged documents. These are custom forms that our employees create and fill out. I need to build a model that will be able to classify the types of each input field of the form in order to automate the collection of information in the database.

Detection is ready and working flawlessly - I have fields positions and boundings (x, y, width, height) for over 350,000 documents. The type of the fields depends on their position in the form, size, and the fields that are nearby. The number of types is fixed, 56.

Obviously, I should use bidirection RNN, but how do I collect features that are responsible for the size ratio and position to each other? Any information would be very helpful.